# Grails - How Do I Show Version And Build Date/Time In My Application

Tags: grails

I'd like to know if there is a way to display the version and build date at the top of my Grails application.

Edit: I should have said I'm looking for the Date/Time the app was built.

Answer (score 3):

In your main template, or wherever.

```
<p style="float:right">Server version: <%=ApplicationHolder.application.metadata['app.version']%></p>
```

You can use `<g:if env="...">` to limit by environments if you wish.

Build *date* is trickier, and probably doesn't mean anything. Do you never build twice on the same day? Same hour? I'm sticking the svn revision in my application version before the build to identify builds, as such:

`_Events.groovy`

```
eventWarStart = { type ->
    addSvnRevisionToAppVersion()
}

private def addSvnRevisionToAppVersion() {
    try {
        DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
        SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
        FSRepositoryFactory.setup();

        SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
        SVNWCClient wcClient = clientManager.getWCClient();
        File baseFile = new File(basedir);
        SVNInfo svninfo = wcClient.doInfo(baseFile, SVNRevision.WORKING);

        def svnRevision = svninfo.getRevision().number;

        String oldVersion = metadata.'app.version'
        String newVersion
        if (oldVersion.matches(/.*\.r\d+/)) {
            newVersion = oldVersion.replaceAll(/\.r\d+/, ".r${svnRevision}");
        }
        else {
            newVersion = oldVersion + ".r${svnRevision}".toString()
        }
        metadata.'app.version' = newVersion
        metadata.persist()

    }
    catch (SVNException ex) {
        println "**************** SVN exception **************"
        println ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Note that instead of appending svn revision, you could just append `new Date()` to get the build date.

Answer (score 1):

i havent tried it my self but there is something like

```
grails set-version 20110101-3

def version = grailsApplication.metadata['app.version']
```

for more info refer to [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any one looking for the solution for grails 3. It can be done by configuring the buildProperties task

```
buildProperties {
    inputs.property("info.app.build.date", new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
}

 <g:meta name="info.app.build.date"/>
```

See [Adding build date and other custom info to war](http://nimavat.me/blog/grails3-add-custom-build-info-to-war)